# Add key translation to Devise locale .yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, translation

The Rails app (4.0.2) I'm currently working on is using devise (3.2.4). When a user sign up devise sends an email with a link to confirm the registration. It's working fine, but my problem is when a user click a second time on the link devise will show a message (alert block)

```
translation missing: en.devise.confirmations.user.{"confirmation_token":["is invalid"]}
```

I found it makes sense because the token is already used and the user's registration validated, but I still need to add the missing translation.

I've tried to add the following sample pair of translation strings to `config/locales/devise.en.yml` file, but without success:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with...."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists...."
      user:
        confirmation_token: 'yepppp!'
```

I'll appreciate any help or guidance on how to add this key pair translation for this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with...."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists...."
      user:
        confirmation_token: "Your translation here"
```

Try it like this because in the warning:

```
en.devise.confirmations.user.{"confirmation_token":["is invalid"]}
```

The "is invalid" doesn't look like a key to me, but the translation string.

Comment: Thanks but my problem persists, your suggestion was the first thing I tried before I even asked here and therefore I've added the "is_invalid" key one level inside the "confirmation_token" key. I'll edit my question with the correct keys as you suggested.